# Difference between "when" and "if" in a sentence

Tags: differences, conditionals, future, when

I was doing a grammar activity and filling in sentences when I came across the instruction: "fill in *when* or *if*."

I was wondering, since these two can be used in a lot of same sentences, what is the difference between sentences like this?

> Chris might call while I'm out this evening. [If/When] he does, can you take a message?

Comment: Ty for editing Sim.

Comment: Related [If and when, when and if](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30697/what-does-if-and-when-mean-and-is-it-the-same-as-when-and-if)

Comment: @ChaosGamer FYI read the FAQ about tagging people's names with an "@" when you want them to receive a notification in their inbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you say **when** something happens, you imply it definitely *will* happen, even if the precise timing is unknown. You use **if** when there's uncertainty about whether the event will happen at all.

It's quite common — especially in informal contexts — to use **when/if** as a shorthand way of signifying **when**, but allowing for the possibility that the event in question may not in fact occur.

Personally I tend to use the composite **when/if** rather than **if/when**, for no reason I can clearly explain. I can't easily search for those hyphenated forms to check others' usage, but I *can* use [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=if%20and%20when,when%20and%20if&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) to check the more extended equivalents. This covers well over a million instances, so I think it's statistically significant. But I have no idea why three out of four people put them the opposite way round to me...
[image: .]

Comment: another great answer from @FumbleFingers.  "If" carries a connotation like something MAY happen, but there is a chance that it may not.  "When" denotes that it WILL happen, it is just a matter of at what point in time the event will carry itself out.

Comment: The technical term is that _when_ **[presupposes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Predicatetypes.pdf)** that it will happen, while _if_ merely assumes possibility. [Presuppositions](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Presuppositiontriggers.pdf) are a big deal, since that's how we manipulate social belief, and their traces are all over English and every other language.

Comment: I wish you would include John Lawler's comment in your answer. I found it most helpful.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I think if the basic question as per OP's title were posted today, I'd vote to migrate to ELL rather than answering. I bet *you* didn't need the actual answer to that question anyway, but John's comment & link is certainly an interesting digression into "related concepts" from a true linguist's perspective. The basic question is entirely covered by my first paragraph (the rest being just *my* attempt at an interesting digression! :). But I doubt the mods would ever delete his comment - so good as it is, I see no real need to copy it into the answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can we assign a truth value to a statement contains when? E.g. "When John will goes to his bed, I will go outside". Can we treat it like a conditional?

Comment: @adosar: Yes - as pointed out in the first paragraph of my answer above, ***If** you say **when** something happens, you imply it **definitely will** happen*. Whereas ***When** you say **if** something happens, you imply it **might or might not** happen*. But they're both "conditional" states (which are not necessarily true or false in any given context). I don't know how or whether that helps you learn how to use English though.

Comment: This is indeed one difference between *if* and *when*. There is another: *when* implies that the consequent is to follow the antecedent fairly quickly, while *if* allows for a gap between the two. Compare the OP's example, which would be fine with *when* with 'Chris might call while I'm out this evening. **If** he does, make sure you let me know (when I come back)'.

Answer (score 2):

When you are sure that something will happen use **when**. Not sure use **if**.

For instance: your mother tells you that tomorrow you are going to town. When she instructs you of what to do, she will say:

> When you are going to town tomorrow buy me sugar.

But when she asks you or your brother that either of you will go town, she will say:

> If you go town tomorrow, buy me sugar.

Answer (score 1):

**if** is used to indicate a condition for an event to take place while **when** is used to indicate time and it is also mostly used to ask questions. Like: **When** did you arrive?

Answer (score 0):

Use "WHEN" for something that will certainly happen, if not use "If".

Answer (score 0):

**IF-THEN**

Causal adverbs determining antecedent and consequent:

*If the Panthers win the tournament, then the Broncos lost the final.*

(The antecedent and the consequent need not be related in time!)

**WHEN-THEN**

Temporal adverb specifying the time

*When the sun rises then it is not dark outside anymore.*